# Is it valid to move a logarithm inside of an expectation?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I have the following derivation for a [latent variable model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf).
$$
\newcommand{\d}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\log p_\theta(x_0)\right]\\
&=^{1.} \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\log \int p_\theta(x_{0:T}) \d{x}_{1:T}\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\log \int \frac{q(x_{1:T})}{q(x_{1:T})}p_\theta(x_{0:T}) \d{x}_{1:T}\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\log \mathbb{E}_{q(x_{1:T})}\left[\frac{p_\theta(x_{0:T})}{q(x_{1:T})}\right]  \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

1. Pull in the latent variables by marginalizing $p_\theta(x_0)$ with respect to $x_{1:T}$

I'm wondering, is it a valid move to do the following:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{q(x_0)}\left[-\mathbb{E}_{q(x_{1:T})}\left[\log \frac{p_\theta(x_{0:T}}{q(x_{1:T})}\right]\right]
$$

I.e., I want to move the log inside of the expectation. It seems *invalid* because

```
log(average(1, 2, 3)) != average(log(1), log(2), log(3))
```

But in the linked paper, the final equation is

[image: Final Equation]

so, I suspect it *must* be possible.

Comment: Switching log and expectation is hardly ever correct.

Comment: I see my mistake here, they are using Jensen's inequality and converting the equality into an less than.

Comment: For a non-constant random variable $E[\log(X)] < \log(E[X])$ - assuming these exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not valid. We know this at least from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proofs) which states that for a convex function $\varphi$, moving it outside of the expectation will make the result smaller or equal to transforming the random variable itself and taking expectation,

$$
\varphi(E[X]) \leq E\left[\varphi(X)\right].
$$

Notice that the last equation from the paper mentioned by you also makes the statement in terms of inequality.